# What does this drawing by Konstantin Tsiolkovsky illustrate, or represent?

Tags: history, design, russia

The Kinetic video (*ironically titled*) [The first rocket scientist - Robert Goddard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAYiqkDOpBQ) begins with an introduction to the even more first rocket scientist Konstantin Tsiolkovsky and shows the following drawing (enhanced screen shot).

The drawing looks like a sphere with three axes shown inside and some little objects, annotations, or items along these six line segments, inside the sphere.

**Question:** What does this drawing by Konstantin Tsiolkovsky illustrate, or represent? What are those little objects or annotations?

[image]

Comment: Their trailer is fun https://youtu.be/ekWOS818g2w and possibly a little more inspiring than *"Space Force!"*

Comment: Tsiolkovsky had a lot of very strange ideas about how rockets would actually work -- as well as an "interesting" method for regenerative cooling.

Comment: @ikrase I wonder if either of those would turn out to be interesting answers if asked about? "Tsiolkovsky's equation" seems based squarely enough in science and math and I don't get a feeling that there's anything strange there, so the possibility that there are "very strange ideas" to be described seems intriguing

Comment: He drew a cryogenic rocket that resembles a trombone welded to the inside of a liquid hydrogen tank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it's impossible task, but was surprized that online archive of Tsiolkovky exists. [Here.](http://tsiolkovsky.org/ru/nauchnoe-nasledie/)

In Russian language it contains all works by Tsiolkovky. There is also English version, but only some of works are translated currenly.

The picture is from the manuskript "Free space" ("Свободное пространство"). You also can find the picture in [Wiki article about Tsiolkovky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky#Tributes).

The manuskript (in Russian) can be found [here](http://tsiolkovsky.org/ru/kosmicheskaya-filosofiya/svobodnoe-prostranstvo/). It have no English translation, unfortunately. The original picture is at page 161 of .pdf in frame. The text of the corresponding chapter can be found at pages 31-36.

**Summary:**

It is ***the first vision of space ship by Tsiolkovky*** (at year 1883). The picture is a ***scheme of the ship***. (Yes, I as suprized too!) No any idea of liquid fuel engine yet, the propulsion is made by powder gun with cannonballs at the ship's rear end (at left side of the pucture). At the front side (right) is a "device to turn" - a mass on tether. Real space steampunk!

I qoute the all text of the chapter in Russian below. If google.translate is too bad, let me know what parts are unclear.

> ОПИСАНИЕ СНАРЯДА. УСТОЙЧИВОСТЬ СНАРЯДА. УСТОЙЧИВОЕ ЦИКЛОИДАЛЬНОЕ
>   ДВИЖЕНИЕ ПРЯМОЛИНЕЙНОЕ НЕУСТОЙЧИВОЕ (КРУГОВОЕ)
>
> Снаряд для путешествия в свободном пространстве, который я сейчас
>   опишу, будет служить для передвижения человека и различных предметов в
>   абсолютной пустоте без пути, т. е. без неподвижной опоры и по
>   желаемому направлению. Вообразим железный или стальной шар, могущий
>   выдержать давление заключённого в нем воздуха. Этот шар снабжён
>   многими круглыми отверстиями: справа,  слева, спереди, сзади — со всех
>   сторон. Отверстия эти, служащие окнами, герметически закрыты толстыми
>   прозрачными стёклами, крепость которых в состоянии выдержать воздушное
>   давление, положим, в сто килограммов на квадратный дециметр. Эта
>   упругость близка к атмосферной у поверхности Земли. Снаряд, взятый как
>   одно целое вместе с заключёнными в нем одушевлёнными и неодушевлёнными
>   телами, как и всякое простое или сложное тело, имеет по крайней мере
>   три оси, взаимно перпендикулярных и проходящих через свободный его
>   центр. Одну из осей (П, П1) назовём полярной, другую (М, M1) —
>   меридиональной, третью (Э, Э1) —экваториальной. Через эти оси можно
>   провести три плоскости. Плоскость, проходящую через две последние оси
>   — меридиональную и экваториальную, назовём экваториальной; пересечение
>   её с шаром — экватором. Плоскость, проходящую через оси — полярную и
>   меридиональную, назовём меридиональной; пересечение же её с шаром —
>   меридианом. Для того чтобы поворотить меридиональную плоскость
>   снаряда, не изменяя положения экваториальной, служит материальная ось,
>   совпадающая с полярной и могущая вращаться вместе с укреплёнными
>   концентрически, на её концах, кругами или колёсами (можно и одно
>   колесо). На том и другом конце меридиональной оси (в плоскости
>   экватора) укреплены два прибора. Один (М), вроде пушки, служит для
>   того, чтобы отбрасывать ядро по направлению меридиональной оси. Другой
>   назначается для того же и имеет также вид толстой трубы с
>   соответствующим ядром значительной величины и плотности. Это ядро
>   отбрасывается уже не порохом или другим взрывчатым веществом как в
>   первом снаряде, а менее значительной силой, например, пружиной или
>   силой руки, причём к ядру этому прикреплена нить большой длины, 
>   которая не позволяет ему удаляться в бесконечность, между тем как
>   каждое выброшенное ядро первой пушки пропадает для путешественников
>   навеки, если только не будет поймано другими путешественниками и
>   возвращено. Пушка служит для перемещения всего снаряда по прямой линии
>   на неопределённо большое расстояние; второй же прибор служит для
>   удаления путешественников на незначительные расстояния — насколько
>   позволяет длина нити, с помощью которой ядро притягивается обратно на
>   прежнее место, точно так же, как и сам снаряд. Посредством этих
>   приборов (пушки) передвижение возможно только по одному направлению.
>   Полярная ось с кругами даёт возможность поворачиваться шару вокруг
>   этой оси и вместе с тем поворачивать меридиан и оба прибора, которые
>   все-таки остаются в плоскости экватора. Силой руки или какой-нибудь
>   машинки я заставляю поворачиваться ось с кругами; вследствие этого
>   поворачивается и шар, но в противоположную сторону и до тех пор, пока 
>   силой руки машины или по инерции движется полярная ось. Когда пушка
>   прошла по экватору желаемое число градусов, я мгновенно останавливаю
>   ось — останавливается и шар с пушкой и меридианом. Теперь остаётся
>   выпалить, и шар с путешественниками помчится в беспредельной плоскости
>   экватора по желаемому направлению. Чтобы иметь возможность
>   поворачивать самый экватор (шара) или пушку в меридиональной
>   плоскости, служит такая же ось с кругами, как и полярная, но
>   совпадающая с экваториальной осью. С помощью полярной оси пушка
>   приобретает любое положение в плоскости экватора, с помощью же
>   экваториальной оси — любое положение в плоскости меридиана. Первая ось
>   поворачивает меридиан шара, вторая — экватор его. Очевидно, с помощью
>   этих двух осей пушке можно дать в пространстве всякое положение, и,
>   следовательно, шар может двигаться во всяком направлении. Движения
>   пушки  сходны с движениями трубы теодолита. Как трубу этого последнего
>   можно направить на любую звезду, так и пушке можно дать желаемое
>   направление и отправить шар с путешественниками к любой звезде.

Comment: As I understand it, the device on the right side of the page is actually the cannon used for propulsion. The device on the left side is used for small translational movements; it's a heavy ball which can be pushed out by hand or by a spring, but it's connected by a thread to the rest of the ship. And the two axes in the middle, which can rotate relative to the hull, are used to change orientation.

Comment: Russian is quite a beautiful language to be honest. Too bad I lack the skills required to turn that beauty into useful information.